# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error using impdp

Tags: oracle, datapump, impdp

I've been provided with a Oracle database dump which I'm attempting to import using the following:

```
impdp myuser/myuser DUMPFILE=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/dumpfile.dmp FULL=y LOGFILE=/u01/app/oracle/oradata/dumplog.log
```

The output is

```
Import: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Fri May 1 09:46:59 2015

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDI-00942: operation generated ORACLE error 942
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Is there anyway I can find out what the problem is or get more information? The user myuser has all privileges.

Comment: i see this is a 12c database, is it multitenant? if so i would guess the problem is that the import doesn't know which PDB to import the data into

Comment: @davegreen100 - this is a non-CDB database so I'm assuming that's not the case, but I'm not hugely familiar with Oracle so if you think there's anything I should check or run to confirm this please let me know.

Comment: i haven't done alot with 12c, but i think running
SELECT * FROM V$PDBS will tell you if there are any pluggable databases.

could you post the contents of the impdp logfile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running though the setup again it turned out this database has not had the `catalog.sql` and `catproc.sql` scripts run on it. Rerunning the import once this has been run resolved this error.